# onchange event select box in joomla

Tags: joomla

how can i put onchange in

```
$regionslistx[]= JHTML::_('select.option', "0", JText::_( '--No Location--' ),'value','text' );
```

or

```
$lists['regionslist' ]= JHTML::_('select.genericlist',  $regionslistx, 'City', '', 'value', 'text', $lx );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, where you have the empty argument, place the function you would like to use:

```
$lists['regionslist' ]= JHTML::_('select.genericlist',  $regionslistx, 'City', 'onchange=\"YOURFUNCTION()\"', 'value', 'text', $lx );
```

Also check the documentation: http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/HTML/JHTMLSelect.html

Comment: @israr in that case, could you please mark the answer as approved? it's the "V" mark next to the answer. This way the question is considered solved.